# Showing address bar in a PWA based on condition

Tags: javascript, angular, paypal, progressive-web-apps

I am implementing PayPal payment system through smart buttons in a PWA app. The problem I am facing is that, by default in a PWA the address bar is hidden, so when the payment dialog for PayPal open it seems as if it's a dialog of the app itself. This is worrying because it doesn't give the user assurance that they're using PayPal's system and that their account is secure.

If I do the same thing through the browser, then the payment window opens in a separate tab with the URL being show.

How can I make it so that the similar behaviour is replicated on the app, or is there a way to show the address bar when the payment dialog is opened?

[Screenshot of the dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lo5UH.jpg)

Comment: if you want PayPal to open in a new browser window, add target="_blank" to the anchor tag.

Comment: @Mathias there is no anchor tag where I can add the target. I'm using PayPal's smart buttons.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part. Not sure how to get around that.

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer about showing an address bar in PWA, but if the goal is to make Smart Buttons open a new tab or redirect, the solution is: don't use Smart Buttons.

Instead, integrate two routes on your server, one for 'Set Up Transaction' and one for 'Capture Transaction', documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/

The first call will return an approval_url that you can simply redirect to (or open a full browser for), rather than using Smart Button JS.

After approval at PayPal in this new window/tab/browser you opened, the return will be to the return_url you specified at Set Up time, which can be a deeplink.

The return should then present an order review/confirmation page (unless you wish to skip this, for which you should specify an [application_context](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#definition-order_application_context) object with `user_action: 'PAY_NOW'` so the user is clicking on the right verbiage for what you're going to be doing.)

Then on this return -- using the provided query string information -- run that second 'Capture Transaction' call.  If the response happens to be INSTRUMENT_DECLINED, simply reopen the original approval_url since this situation is recoverable ([some details on the situation here](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server), though that demo and Handle Funding Failures guide are for Smart Buttons, but the concept is the same). If the response is success or any other error, proceed accordingly.